# Can't we consider that EmDrive is Pushing against Space itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, spacetime

When something move through space it pushes against something else in space with equal force.

However, EmDrive warps space around. So can't we say it's pushing against space itself, and thus momentum is conserved?

Just something that came up in my mind.

Comment: Where have you heard that the EmDrive warps space?

Comment: More on [EmDrive](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+emdrive).

Comment: "Pushing against space" does not make any sense, and the EMDrive is...controversial, to say the least. Please ask questions founded in accepted physics

Answer (score 2):

No, we can't say that. The vacuum of space cannot carry momentum. "Pushing against space itself" is just a roundabout way to say "pushing against nothing at all", or in other words "violating conservation of momentum".

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things an EmDrive could 'push against' - some as yet unknown or ill understood field for instance (dark matter, dark energy, something else).

It could also couple to the gravity field - in which case it would be pushing on space itself. The coupling to gravity would be miraculously strong though, so that's not likely.

The main problem with the EmDrive lies not in possible connections to fields, but rather in the simple experimental fact of whether it works or not.

Its fashionable to dismiss the EmDrive as "violating conservation of momentum", but there are so many ways to get reaction without seeing the rocket exhaust. Take beta decay for instance - a reactionless pulse until physics posited and later discovered the neutrino.

Answer (score 0):

Most surely the em drive is just miving its center of mass during the small intervall they measure something.

To clarify... i am guessing is an inteligent scam or honest mistake. If you reorganise the inside of a wagon you generate "thrust" for the small intervals needed to move the center of mass. The EMdrive experiment only detects temporary thrust, not continuous. I am conjeturing it is the same phenomena.

Put a sandclock on a scale and you will measure "thrust" (variation of measured weight). Not even in the DiscWorld you will see a spaceship using sandclocks.

Comment: This answers assumes that the EmDrive is *not* complete bunk that the rest of the physics community knows it to be (see any of the other questions on this site about the device for more info)

Comment: @kylekanos Hey no! I just guess how the scam works.